# multiple delimiters (words) in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

How can multiple delimiters be used for the split() function? I want to use more than two words as the delimiters but I'm unsure how that is possible.

```
c = Trim(t.value)
arr = Split(c, "hello" , "hi")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the multiple words first using replace and then use that in split.

e.g.

```
mystring= Replace(mystring, "hello", "#")
mystring= Replace(mystring, "hi", "#")
mystring= Replace(mystring, "thanks", "#")
newstring= Split(mystring, "#")
```

Comment: I want to be able to pull the delimiter along with the word before it once splitting. Is there a way to get back?

Comment: Didn't get that. Can you explain?

Comment: if you want to pull the delimiter, just repeat the "split" after each replacement

Comment: I mean like if I split a cell on "hi" , "bye" , and "thanks" I want to be able to pull the words previous to each them while also having the correct delimiter next to the word. So if "hi" was after Father and "bye" after mother I want to be able to pull out Father "hi" and mother "bye"

Comment: That would just require a logic building. Use a similar way to do that. BTW, still unsure of your requirement.

Comment: I'll post a link to a new question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you could go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim t As String
    Dim arr As Variant, seps As Variant, sep As Variant

    seps = Array("hello", "hi") '<--| define your seperators list

    t = "hello i would hello like to hi split this string hello with multiple hello separators hi" '<--| string to split

    t = " " & t & " " '<--| add trailing blank to catch possible "border" 'separators'
    For Each sep In seps
        t = Replace(t, " " & sep & " ", "|") 'turn all separators into one only
    Next sep
    t = Trim(t) '<--| remove trailing blanks
    If Left(t, 1) = "|" Then t = Right(t, Len(t) - 1) '<--| remove any initial 'separator'
    If Right(t, 1) = "|" Then t = Left(t, Len(t) - 1) '<--| remove any final 'separator'
    arr = Split(t, "|")

End Sub
```